# Is there an HTML tag whose contents simply cannot contain JavaScript?

Tags: html, browser, xss

Here's a dumb question, and the answer is probably "No", but it doesn't hurt to ask...

I need to ingest formatted text as HTML markup, and later emit the HTML to display the formatted text. This is a REALLY COMMON scenario. Even StackOverflow has to deal with it. (If you think markdown is inherently safe from XSS, Google "markdown xss".) After much Googling, it has become clear to me that both whitelist and blacklist HTML sanitizers have their issues, not least of which is that clever bad guys always seem to find a way to get around them.

Now, obviously, every browser knows how to parse HTML and execute JavaScript (or other script languages). XSS "sanitizer evasion" attacks rely on employing creative constructs that are not caught by most sanitizers, but that are recognized by the browser as JavaScript code to be executed.

So, since the (hopefully sanitized) user-supplied HTML (or user-supplied markdown, converted to HTML) is contained as a **child** of some HTML element in my website, it seems that the obvious solution is to somehow tell the browser **not to execute any script code contained in that element's children**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is not possible with current browsers, and I don't really see it being that useful of a feature to add. Let's say we create a new element in HTML6 called `<safe>` and the idea is that there is absolutely no javascript executed inside this element. We will assume that it works flawlessly with zero bugs. So, you'd do something like this on the server-side.

```
<safe>
   $content
</safe>
```

Where `$content` represents untrusted content. Seems good, except there's one problem. What if `$content` has a terminating `</safe>` tag inside it? So, you may say... simple! we just have to encode `</safe>` and we'll be good. That is basically already where we are with XSS. If you can encode `</safe>` you can encode `<script>`, `<img>`, and whatever else.

Maybe there is a good way to implement this, but it seems very dependent on server-side encoding anyway.

While there may be bugs in markdown from time-to-time, using a regularly updated library for this is way better than making your own solution using a whitelist. If it's good enough for StackOverflow, Reddit, GitHub, Jira, etc.... it's probably good enough for what you're building.

Of course, always follow the [XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).